# Going over a record type in SML?

Tags: list, tuples, sml

I have this special type, taken.

```
type taken = {course:string, student:int, grade:real};
```

I want to go over a list of this type, and find a matching course and student. If I find one, then I have to change the grade to a preset variable G. Below is what I have right now.

```
exception unTaken;
fun updateGrade (T:taken, []:taken list) = raise unTaken
  | updateGrade (T, {course = #course(T), student = #student(T), ...}::rest) =
    {course = #course(T), student = #student(T), grade = G}
  | updateGrade (T, TL) = updateGrade (T, (tl TL));
```

---

If the end of the taken list is reached, I raise an exception.
The second option is, if it matches the course and name from T, then it sets it to the same course and student, but changes G to the preset variable. Otherwise, keep going through the list.

---

The issue is, I keep getting errors similar to the ones below

```
stdIn:3.21-3.28 Error: syntax error: deleting  HASH ID
stdIn:3.43-3.52 Error: syntax error: deleting  HASH ID LPAREN
stdIn:3.53 Error: syntax error found at RPAREN
```

Any idea what's going on? Can I also ask how to go around debugging these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things that go wrong:

- As a convention, keep variable names lowercase and value constructors uppercase.
- Don't use the same variable twice in the same pattern (you're using `T` in several places). Some pattern matching languages (Erlang, Prolog) allow for this  to mean that the values that those variables cover should be equivalent, but Standard ML does not support this.
- Don't use the record getters `#course` / `#student` in the pattern. They're macros that behave like functions. You can pattern match on parts of records, but the syntax is slightly different (see the second example below).

Here is a fixed version:

```
fun updateGrade (t1 : taken, []) = raise unTaken
  | updateGrade (t1 : taken, t2::ts) =
    if #course t1 = #course t2 andalso #student t1 = #student t2
    then t1 :: ts
    else t2 :: updateGrade (t1, ts)
```

Here is a fixed version that performs pattern matching on records:

```
fun updateGrade (t1 : taken, []) = raise unTaken
  | updateGrade (t1 as { course = course1, student = student1, ... },
                 (t2 as { course = course2, student = student2, ... })::ts) =
    if course1 = course2 andalso student1 = student2
    then t1 :: ts
    else t2 :: updateGrade (t1, ts)
```

> Can I also ask how to go around debugging these errors?

Since compilers are still, in general, inherently unhelpful when syntax errors occur, I'm not sure there are better solutions than to show the code to someone else, or compare it against the most similar textbook example you know. Standard ML does lack example code, and record syntax is more fiddly than most of the rest of the language.

Comment: I think you've correctly identified the problem and solution, but I'm not sure, because your terminology seems very strange to me. Does "to unify `T` with `{course = #student(T), ...}`" mean "to have a subpattern `{course = #student(T), ...}` that refers to the value variable `T`"?

Comment: @ruakh: I suspect that Andrew's intent is to use the same pattern variable twice and have the pattern succeed only if they match the same substructure. I'll rephrase my answer to make less of an assumption as to Andrew's intent.

Comment: You are right about the unhelpful nature of compiler messages. In my experience, SML/NJ is one of the least helpful compilers. Do you know if e.g. Poly/ML is any better?

Comment: @JohnColeman: It is my experience that both Poly/ML's and Moscow ML's errors are easier to read.